# EMC Celerra - cliff's notes for dummies?

Tags: emc, celerra

I just bought my first EMC Celerra NX4.

I'm starting to configure it and have a few questions:

1. What is Celerra Network Server?
2. What are the Celerra iscsi utilities?
3. Is there a very basic "how to" guide online somewhere?

I can figure it out long term, but I'm needing to at least get a basic grasp of the ins and outs of one in the next few days before I ship it to its final destination at one of our offices.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there no information on the Celerra web site? I'm surprised you've purchased a product you appear to have no information about.

Comment: I have the user manual and I've configured a basic CIFS share/server on it.  I'm asking along the lines of a "teach yourself celerra in 24 hours" thing...which I can't seem to find on their site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to get a "Dummy's Guide to Enterprise Storage", because enterprise storage isn't for dummies.

You're dealing with technology that people spend thousands of dollars on just for a week or two of training. Learning it on your own is going to take some legwork.

Here are some resources that I've found. Take notes, play, and for the love of $DEITY don't do anything important on it yet.

Introduction to EMC CLARiiON & Celerra Unified Platform Storage Device Technology
http://ukraine.emc.com/collateral/hardware/white-papers/h4208-an-intro-emc-clariion-hard0drive-tech-wp.pdf

Introduction to EMC Celerra Unified Storage (A Detailed Review)
http://www.emc.com/collateral/hardware/white-papers/h6861-introduction-celerra-unified-storage-wp.pdf

Introduction to Using EMC Celerra with VMware vSphere 4 (Appied Best Practices Guide)
http://www.emc.com/collateral/hardware/white-papers/h6337-introduction-using-celerra-vmware-vsphere-wp.pdf
(if you're using VMware)

Comment: That'll work for others that want an answer during a search so you get the check.  My answer fulfilled my needs though since it included what you had posted as well.  I understand "enterprise storage" I just wasn't familiar with EMC's gui and software usage.

Answer (score 0):

I found walkthroughs and videos on the Powerlink (internal EMC site) support site once I registered for it.  Lots of good information there.